# Alternative way to connect to Teamviewer "server" computer

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm looking for a solution like UltraVNC, UltraViewer, AnyDesk or whatever in order to handle a TeamViewer session on a remote computer to make maintenance operations on it.
I didn't find any useful information on these sofwares websites on how to do that.

I need basically to install the software on Windows 10 (my computer), the TeamViewer i have to connect to are also on Windows but it would be unlikely to install another RDC on them.

I take any advice or experience about that.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try **[LiteManager](https://litemanager.com)** for remote desktop! ;)

Comment: Wercome to SuperUser, Tom ! Thanks, i'll give it a try soon and i'll update this thread.